# Encryption/Decryption using bcrypt library

Tags: c++, encryption, cng

I am calling the `BCryptDecrypt` function which is returning an error. I get the error 120 using `getlasterror` which means this function is not supported in this system (in msdn).

```
status = BCryptDecrypt( hKey, pbInput, cbInput, NULL, NULL, sizeof(DWORD), NULL, 0, &pcbResult, BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING);
```

`pbInput` is the pointer to address which contains the data to be decrypted, `cbInput` is the length of the file  and `pcbResult` will get the size of the output file (decrypted data). `BCryptEncrypt` is working fine but `BCryptDecryptis` not working.

Can anyone please help me out?
few lines of code related to decrypt:

status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&hAlgorithm , BCRYPT_AES_ALGORITHM , NULL , 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        return;
    }

```
DWORD cbKey = 0;
DWORD cbData =0;

status = BCryptSetProperty(hAlgorithm , BCRYPT_CHAINING_MODE , (PBYTE)BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_ECB , sizeof(BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_ECB) , 0);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
{
    return;
}

status = BCryptGetProperty(hAlgorithm,
                    BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH,
                    (LPBYTE)&cbData,
                    sizeof(DWORD),
                    &cbKey,
                    0);

LPBYTE pbKey = (BYTE*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap() , 0 , cbData);
LPCSTR szpwd = (LPCSTR)Getpwd();

BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hKey = NULL;
status = BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey(hAlgorithm,
                                    &hKey,
                                    pbKey,
                                    cbData,
                                    (PUCHAR)szpwd,
                                    (ULONG)strlen(szpwd),
                                    0);

if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
{
    if(hAlgorithm)
    {
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlgorithm,0);
    }
    if(pbKey)
    {
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pbKey);
    }
    return;
}

DWORD pcbResult = 0;
status = BCryptDecrypt( hKey,
                        pbInput,
                        cbInput,
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        sizeof(DWORD),
                        NULL,
                        0,
                        &pcbResult,
                        BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING);

DWORD cbError = GetLastError();
if(cbError != 0)
{
LPCSTR messageBuffer = NULL;

size_t size = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                             NULL, cbError, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPSTR)&messageBuffer, 0, NULL);
```

Comment: Show some code please

Comment: Wrong .net version installed?

Comment: Can you briefly explain what you want to say.I am writing code in mfc in vs-8.

Comment: BCryptEncrypt is working fine but BCryptDecrypt giving run time error.